# Proof step in Rademacher's Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

In the proof of Rademacher's theorem, we assume that $f: \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$ is a Lipschitz function and $v \in \Bbb R^n$ is a vector with $\Vert v \Vert = 1$. Our aim is to show, that 
$$ \mathrm D_v f(x) = v \cdot \text{grad} f(x) \; ,$$
where $\mathrm D_v f(x)$ is the directional derivative of $f$ at the point $x$ in the direction $v$, and on the right sight of the equation we have the euclidean scalar product of $v$ and the gradient of $f$ at the point $x$. In the proof we have shown, that 
$$
\int_{\Bbb R^n} \mathrm D_v f(x) \zeta(x) \; \mathrm dx = \int_{\Bbb R^n} [v \cdot \text{grad}f(x)] \zeta(x) \; \mathrm dx
$$
for any $\zeta \in C_c^\infty(\Bbb R^n)$. 
Why is this enough to know, that 
$$ \mathrm D_v f(x) = v \cdot \text{grad} f(x) $$
holds?

Comment: Just to make sure: Did you prove that both $D_v f$ and $v\cdot \text{grad} f$ are locally integrable? (Can you also provide the reference?)

Comment: The proof is from "Evans - Geometric Measure Theory and Fine Properties of Functions", but it can also be found here, Lemma 3.9 on page 9: https://www.google.ch/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=35&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiby5Grr7XJAhWCuhoKHfiVAeg4HhAWCD0wBA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fvrs.amsi.org.au%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2Fsites%2F6%2F2014%2F09%2FHausdorff_-_Thornett.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGKm-w9eIqVR181Nx9pTHE9OeTzyw&sig2=ptt0MtVm4IuJec3Ff1R8sQ

Answer (score 1):

A start: Take the contrapositive and suppose $f$ and $g$ were well-behaved functions that were not equal (what is a sufficient criterion for well-behavedness?). You could figure then there would be some $\zeta$ for which the integral equality would not hold, for example, if $\zeta$ were some kind of smooth bump function whose bump was in the neighborhood around some point at which $f$ and $g$ are not equal.